# Tamago-su preparation

Tags: eggs, ingredient-selection, vinegar

In [tamago-su](http://applecidervinegarhub.org/2014/07/17/samurai-health-drink-egg-vinegar-an-ancient-folk-remedy/) recipe, egg shell is first dissolved in vinegar. Then the membrane is broken apart and the white and yolk are poured into vinegar. But I am not sure if these should be poured into the vinegar that dissolved the egg shell, or a new glass of vinegar.

Can you please tell me the correct way?

Answer (score 6):

The way the recipe reads is:

> Split open the membrane and dump the egg back in Vinegar & mix well.

("Back" being the operative word there IE, "Dump it back into the vinegar") with the intent of consuming all parts of the egg, including the dissolved shell (the source of calcium), as reflected in the post-script to the recipe:

> ...Egg Vinegar tonic to be an important source of strength and power. The
>   protein, Calcium, Vitamins in the egg are well absorbed by our bodies.

The recipe also does not mention any additional vinegar after the 1 cup used at the beginning of the recipe.

So yes. Pour it back into the vinegar with the shell dissolved in it.

Just a note, make certain to wash your egg well before placing it into the vinegar & keep in mind that from a food safety standpoint, you are consuming raw egg. You should probably try following food safety practices similar to those for home-made mayonnaise.